# FileSystemWatcher c# no error and isn't working

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I don't know how to integrate the code I wrote on c# with the FileSystemWatcher class

```
    public static void watcherFunc()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Develop\Desktop\test\");
        fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    // Define the event handlers. 
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        MessageBox.Show("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }
```

I tried to call it in form1 lead event.... I tried to read how to do it and google it with no luck please help...thank you !

Comment: i have not used c# in a while, but if you declare a watcher in a function, isn't it out of scope when that function finishes?

Comment: Well I guess it is what happens =) sound logic when you say it

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell the problem is that your `FileSystemWatcher` goes out of scope when you finish the method.  Therefore it is no longer active for you to catch events.

Try it like so:

```
FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Documents and ettings\Develop\Desktop\test\");
public void Initialize() //initialization or Constructor
{
    fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

// Define the event handlers. 
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
    MessageBox.Show("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}
```

See [FileWatcher Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/filesystemwatcher) for more help if you need it

Comment: still not working i tried it with your code + I saw the tutorial and tried to do it in that way and still nothing no error and no result

Comment: I can add a timer maybe it will work but it isnt good for me I want a live monitoring not every 5 min...

Comment: ok I switched the OnChanged event to Created event and now it works but I still don't understand why it didn't work with the OnChanged

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue.  This is what I used: http://pastebin.com/wZYiDq54.  When I open a notepad file and save it in that directory, the messagebox shows up